# Too many php56.cgi processes on wordpress website, how can I reduce?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache

My shared hosting's apache instance keeps crashing after I've moved a wordpress website to dreamhost from godaddy. I've been told by that there are too many php processes running and once they exceed 8, it freezes apache. They've told me I need to optimize the website or upgrade to VPS.

Any idea what could be causing this, how I could reduce the amount of php processes, or optimize the site? It worked fine on godaddy before moving it.

Here is the error from the log file:

```
[Mon Sep 28 05:23:05 2015] [error] mod_fcgid: domain=www.mydomain.com too many /dh/cgi-system/php56.cgi processes (current:8, max:8), skip the spawn request
```

Comment: Could you enable FastCGI?

Comment: mod_fcgid is FastCGI, so it looks like it is enabled.

Comment: Not really, mod_fastcgi is FastCGI. mod_fcgid is quite different with mod_fastcgi and generally end up with more processes. This is why I asked if you can enable mod_fastcgi instead.

Comment: Some related answer http://superuser.com/a/514555